# What do these macros do?

Tags: c, pic

I have inherited some heavily obfuscated and poorly written PIC code to modify. There are two macros here:

```
#define TopByteInt(v) (*(((unsigned char *)(&v)+1)))
#define BottomByteInt(v) (*((unsigned char *)(&v)))
```

Is anyone able to explain what on earth they do and what that means please?

Thanks :)

Comment: They are macros to fetch the top and bottom byte half of a 16 bit integer type

Comment: If you can't decode these simple expressions then you are going to have trouble with more complicated code...  which bit of it is unclear?

Comment: The "poorly written" part is mostly the useless parenthesis while a required (for some arguments) pair is missing: `#define TopByteInt(v) (*((unsigned char *)&(v) + 1))` would be better...

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I've been writing embedded code for over twenty years and have no difficulty in writing clear, easy-to-follow, well structured code. Which this is not.

Comment: @malso, I wasn't necessarily saying these macros were poorly written, just I could not fathom what they meant. Although, having had it explained to me, I think it's a bizarre way of writing it.

Comment: Many thanks to all for the explanations.

Comment: You've never seen aliasing a value of one type as another type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(*((unsigned char *)(&v)))
```

It casts the v (a 16 bit integer) into a char (8 bits), doing this you get only the bottom byte.

```
(*(((unsigned char *)(&v)+1)))
```

This is the same but it gets the address of v and sum 1 byte, so it gets only the top byte.

It'll only work as expected if v is a 16 bits integer.

Comment: Huh? The first macro clearly uses `&v` too, it doesn't "cast the integer".

Comment: Yes, you're right, it gets the first 8 bits portion stored in the address of v, that would be more precise.

Comment: I like this explanation the best as it points out that the "+1" is accessing the next byte. That's a salient point I was not seeing. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

They access a 16-bit integer variable one byte at a time, allowing access to the most significant and least significant byte halves. Little-endian byte order is assumed.

Usage would be like this:

```
uint16_t v = 0xcafe;
const uint8_t v_high = TopByteInt(&v);
const uint8_t v_low  = BottomByteInt(&v);
```

The above would result in `v_high` being `0xca` and `v_low` being `0xfe`.

It's rather scary code, it would be cleaner to just do this arithmetically:

```
#define TopByteInt(v)    (((v) >> 8) & 0xff)
#define BottomByteInt(v) ((v) & 0xff)
```

Comment: PIC is a 8-bit microcontroller and maybe it was written in order to avoid unneccessary shifts

Comment: Your way is how I'd write it, only I'd not use bloomin' macros!

Comment: @DiBosco Me neither, probably, but it's handy to stay close to the original question some times.

Answer (score 1):

Ugg.

Assuming you are on a little-endian platform, that looks like it might meaningfully be recorded as

```
#define TopByteInt(v) (((v) >> 8) & 0xff)
#define BottomByteInt(v) ((v) & 0xff)
```

It is basically taking the variable v, and extracting the least significant byte (`BottomByteInt`) and the next more significant byte (`TopByteInt`) from that. 'TopByte' is a bit of a misnomer if v isn't a 16 bit value.